# avoid leaking info whether the user is denied access or typed the incorrect password

Tags: ssh, pam, attacks

I am currently tinkering with the `sshd_config` and `/etc/security/access.d` for a large system with 10k+ users. There are so many different ways of restricting user access and it makes my head spin a bit trying to find "the best way". In short

- We can restrict access using our ACLs
- Restrict access on the loadbalancer using a local firewall
- Restrict access using the sshd_config
- Restrict access using our PAM config

A very stripped down version of our PAM stack for sshd looks like

```
auth       requisite                              pam_faillock.so preauth deny=9 unlock_time=60
auth       required                               pam_env.so
auth       required                               pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth       [success=2 ignore=ignore default=bad]  pam_ssh_user_auth.so
auth       [success=1 ignore=ignore default=bad]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth       [default=die]                          pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=9 unlock_time=60
auth       requisite                              pam_access.so
auth       sufficient                             pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=9 unlock_time=60
auth       [success=1 ignore=ignore default=bad]  pam_2fa.so 
auth       [default=die]  pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=9 unlock_time=60
auth       sufficient     pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=9 unlock_time=60
auth       include        postlogin
```

In short this accepts either username+(password OR public key) login.
Since the 2fa pings the users phone, this code is only asked if the first factor is accepted.

*Example of adversary incorrectly guessing the username / password*

```
~ ❯❯❯ ssh user@testmachine                                         
(user@testmachine) Password: 
(user@testmachine) Password: 
(user@testmachine) Password: 
user@testmachine: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

*Example of correctly guessing password of user without login access*

```
~ ❯❯❯ ssh user@testmachine 
(user@machine) Password: 
Connection closed by IP port 22
```

To summarize

- If an adversary writes in the wrong password, the password prompt shows up 3 times.
- If the adversary correctly guesses the password for an user which is not allowed to login, the password prompt shows up 1 time.

**Is there any way to not leak whether the user is denied from entering the system, and whether the user typed in the correct password?**

This does not *have* to be done with PAM as long as, as little as possible information is leaked.